# Linear operator property

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces and $T\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. I want to prove that if 
$$T[B_X^\circ]=B_Y^\circ,$$
then
$$\hat{T}\colon X/\text{ker }T \ni x+\text{ker }T\mapsto Tx\in Y$$
is an isometric isomorphism. Any ideas on how to approach this proof?

For notation:
$$T[B_X^\circ]=\{Tx\ \colon \|x\|<1\},$$
$$B_Y^\circ=\{y\ \colon \|y\|<1\}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. $\hat T$ enjoys the same properties as $T$, that is $\hat T (B^\circ_{X/N}) = B^\circ_Y$ for $N=\ker T$.
2. $\hat T$ is an isomorphism with $\|\hat T\| = \|\hat T^{-1}\| = 1$.

**Spoilers:**

> 1. The inclusion $ \hat T (B^\circ_{X/N}) \supseteq B^\circ_Y $ is trivial.
> 2. Let $x\in X$ and $\|x-v_k\| \to \|x + N\| \in (0,1)$. Then, we have
>
>    $$ \|\hat T(x + N)\| = \|T(x - v_k)\| =  \| x - v_k \| \left\|T \left(\frac{x - v_k}{\| x - v_k \|} \right) \right\| \le \| x - v_k \| \to \| x - N \| < 1. $$
>
>    That is,
>     $$ \hat T (B^\circ_{X/N}) \subseteq B^\circ_Y. $$